# Appending to an SVG with D3 from an Angular HTTP promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, typescript

I'm using D3 in an Angular directive to build a very simple chart with data queried from my database.

When the directive is constructed, I call

```
private initializePlot() {
    this.svg = d3.select(this.$element[0]).append("svg")
        .attr("width", Number(this.width) + this.margin.left + this.margin.right)
        .attr("height", Number(this.height) + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.margin.left + "," + this.margin.top + ")");

    this.svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x-axis")
        .call(this.xAxis);
}
```

Which appends the SVG, saves it to the scope, and adds the axis.

I then call from an AngularJs Http Promise to draw the actual data on the SVG:

```
private plotData(data) {
    this.xValues.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return new Date(d['date']); }));
    this.yValues.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.data; }));

    this.$timeout(() => {
        this.svg.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", this.line.bind(this));
    });
```

Here is what the graph should look like if it renders properly:

[image: graph]

The chart data (line added in plotData) won't be added to the SVG until I requery my database, at which point it will render.

I initially thought this was because a digest cycle wasn't processing the data since it is being plotted asynchronously, but wrapping the function call in a timeout is supposed to trigger a digest cycle, so I do not know why the line will not render when plotData is called.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated as I'm pretty stumped here.

Comment: Is the path element created on SVG for the first time, without requery? 
if not, I guess there is some issue with scope.apply(). Try commenting the timeout and append the path & data in SVG right after u set variable domains

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your response. The path element is not created until I requery. Nothing from plotData is added to the SVG despite being called. I tried your suggestion of adding data directly and it worked with static data, still need a way to apply it dynamically though!